# Runtime Mesh Simplification (Decimation) in Unity

Tags: unity, mesh

I'm trying to runtime decimate a mesh in Unity. (Open to new methods other than the repo I found.)

Currently trying to get this to work https://github.com/Whinarn/UnityMeshSimplifier/

As a sanity check, I've tried reducing my mesh to just 5 vertices but somehow it doesn't seem to look any different. (dragged on mesh gameobject. bool true for editor test for Start sanity test)

The before and after vertexCount seems to be the same.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityMeshSimplifier;

public class SimplifyChildren : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float quality = 0.5f;
    public SimplificationOptions so;

#if UNITY_EDITOR
    public bool testInEditor = false;

    private void Start()
    {
        SimplifyIfComplex(5);
    }
#endif 

    // simplify is mesh contains too many vertices
    public void SimplifyIfComplex(int maxV = 10000,MeshFilter[] meshFilters = null)
    {
        int vertexcount = 0;
        if(meshFilters == null) meshFilters = GetComponentsInChildren<MeshFilter>();

        foreach (MeshFilter meshFilter in meshFilters)
        {
            vertexcount += meshFilter.sharedMesh.vertexCount;
        }

        

        if (vertexcount > maxV)
        {
            quality = (float)maxV / (float)vertexcount;
            Simplify(meshFilters,quality);
        }

        print(quality.ToString("F6") + " " + vertexcount + " " + maxV);
    }

    public void Simplify(MeshFilter[] meshFilters,float quality)
    {
        if(meshFilters==null) meshFilters = GetComponentsInChildren<MeshFilter>();

        int vertexcount = 0;
        foreach (MeshFilter meshFilter in meshFilters)
        {
            SimplifyMeshFilter(quality,so,meshFilter);
            vertexcount += meshFilter.sharedMesh.vertexCount;
        }
        print(vertexcount);
    }

    private static void SimplifyMeshFilter(float quality,SimplificationOptions so,MeshFilter meshFilter)
    {
        Mesh sourceMesh = meshFilter.sharedMesh;
        if (sourceMesh == null) // verify that the mesh filter actually has a mesh
            return;

        // Create our mesh simplifier and setup our entire mesh in it
        var meshSimplifier = new UnityMeshSimplifier.MeshSimplifier();
        meshSimplifier.SimplificationOptions = so;
        meshSimplifier.Initialize(sourceMesh);

        // This is where the magic happens, lets simplify!
        meshSimplifier.SimplifyMesh(quality);

        // Create our final mesh and apply it back to our mesh filter
        meshFilter.sharedMesh = meshSimplifier.ToMesh();
        print(meshSimplifier.ToMesh().vertexCount);
    }
}
```

---

For SimplificationOptions, I have tried using the default set, shown in screen recording here below.

Here is a sanity check with built in sphere where truly nothing seems to happen. https://gyazo.com/e20f6aedaeb872442ea01f638713a638

Comment: To make this a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example, you'll need to show us the simplification options you're using, and what source mesh you're running it on. Have you tried it with a simple test case like the built-in sphere primitive, to check whether the initial mesh makes a difference?

Comment: Yes, just sanity checked with built in sphere... no difference 505 vertexcount before and after. at this point i'm not sure if i am applying this correctly? Using default Simplification Options

Comment: "default" is less descriptive than editing your question to show what those defaults actually are. And what outputs are you getting from the `print` statements along the way?

Comment: @DMGregory https://gyazo.com/e20f6aedaeb872442ea01f638713a638

Comment: Turns out this is due to Simplification Options causing a silent fail. Not setting the property seems to fix it.